# Assigning cell value to an array based on a condition

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

This is my first time using array in VBA. I was trying to check the value of my array based on certain condition.

I check my array value through the **[Locals Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274949/how-to-print-two-dimensional-array-in-immediate-window-in-vba)**. The window is empty. What did I do wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

'define dynamic array
Dim sn As Variant 
Dim i As Long

'Loop through all the row
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 12).Value = "Renewal Reminder" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 12).Value) Then
    'assign cell value to array
    sn = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Debug.Print "aaa" ' there are 8 cell values that meet the condition
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

**Update**

`Dim sn as Varient` was highlighted with Error

> user-defined type not defined

Comment: Without seeing your spreadsheet I can't say for sure, but here's a few thoughts.  Is this using 1 or 0 based indexing?  (Is column A1 "row 1 column 1" or is it "row 0 column 0"?)  Have you set a breakpoint on the sn or Debug lines?  Does the watch window still hold the value once the few milliseconds it takes the function to finish are over?

Comment: You are not using `sn` as an array - you are simply storing the value of a single cell into the variable.  (FWIW, your `And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 12).Value)` is pointless because. if `Cells(i, 12).Value = "Renewal Reminder"` is `True` then you already know that that cell is not `Empty`.)

Comment: @YowE3K ahha, you are right.

Comment: Your edit says that you have a line saying `Dim sn as Varient`, but that does not appear in your posted code.  If the error is correct, you have a typo.

Comment: @YowE3K oh god, thanks I misspelled `Variant` to `Varient`

Comment: Now, what are you trying to do with an array?  Are you trying to collect all the values from column A where column L is "Renewal Reminder"?

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, I'm trying to get the cell value and stored in a dynamic array. The array values will be used to send email reminders. In JavaScript I can declare the array and use `array.push()` method. VBA seems alot more harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the typo showing in the error message, you are not actually using `sn` as an array - you are simply storing each value in a scalar variable, replacing what was previously in that variable.

The following should work for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'define dynamic array
    Dim sn As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim sn(1 To 1)
    cnt = 0
    'Loop through all the row
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 12).Value = "Renewal Reminder" Then
            'assign cell value to array
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve sn(1 To cnt)
            sn(cnt) = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Debug.Print "aaa" ' there are 8 cell values that meet the condition
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To cnt
        Debug.Print sn(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

As mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016820/6535336) by [Chemiadel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6637260/chemiadel), it is better to declare your variables using the appropriate base type if you know what that is.

So, if you know that column A contains text, replace `Dim sn As Variant` with

```
Dim sn() As String
```

or, if it is a double-precision number, use

```
Dim sn() As Double
```

etc.  If column A could contain various different types, using `Variant` could be appropriate.

Note: You don't have to include the `()` when using `Variant` because `Variant` variables can switch happily between being scalars, arrays, objects, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I was looking at [something similar](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dynamic-array.html) but you're faster and better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare Array with this way and avoid **Variant** data type :

1. Static Array : fixed-size array

   ```
   dim sn(10) as String
   ```
2. Dynamic Array : you can size the array while the code is running.

   ```
   dim sn() as String
   ```

Use ReDim Preserve to expand an array while preserving existing values

```
ReDim Preserve sn(UBound(sn) + 10)
```

Check the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-arrays#declaring-a-dynamic-array)

Comment: You can also define `sn` as a `Variant` using `Dim sn As Variant`, and then place an array in it.

Comment: but I'm not sure the size of my array, as it purely depends on the condition.  In that case, `ReDim Preserve sn(UBound(sn) + 10) ` only adds 10, what if I had more than 10?

Comment: use ReDim and specify the type of the array in first avoid Variant datatype